# Required Fields error check not working

Tags: php, mysql, forms, error-handling

As the title says I am building a registration page, I am following a tutorial and building the code as I go, and for some reason rather than printing the error, it's just posting in the url, here is my code.

```
    <?php include ("core/init.php"); ?>
<?php include ("includes/overall/header.php"); 

if (empty($_POST) === false) {
$required_fields = array('username', 'password', 'password_again', 'email');
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
    if (empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) === true) {
        $errors[] = 'Fields marked with an * are required';
        break 1;
    }

}


}
print_r($errors);
?>
<h1>Register</h1>
<form action="" method"post">
<ul>
    <li>
        Username*:<br>
        <input type="text" name="username">
    </li>
    <li>
        Password*:<br>
        <input type="password" name="password">
    </li>
    <li>
        Password Again*:<br>
        <input type="password" name="password_again">
    </li>
    <li>
        E-mail*:<br>
        <input type="text" name="email">
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="submit" value="Register">
    </li>
</ul>

</form>
<?php include ("includes/overall/footer.php") ; ?>
```

Comment: Try changing `$errors[] = 'Fields marked with an * are required';` for `$errors = 'Fields marked with an * are required';` -- PS: "=== true" is unnecessary. Just makes your code a little confusing. This does the job and feels clearer. `if(empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields))` -- PPS: I realize you're probably just learning, but just in case: Avoid `<br>` like pest ; here, use `<label>` and set it to `display: block;` with CSS.

Comment: thanks for the tips, yes I am learning through tutorials so happy to listen to any advice anyone is willing to share.

Comment: Oh, while I'm here. The "1" after `break` is useless. A numeric argument serves to say how many nested loops you want to exit. But here, like in 99.9 % cases, it's one. And one doesn't need to be specified. So `break;` is fine and even better. -- And since you asked for it, your <?php> blocks are opened strangely. If you put the `include()` in a separate block from the rest, that's fine, but put it with the other, not alone and then the other one is with the rest of the code. Oh yeah, and if a tag (say, <?php) contains more than one line, always put it on its own line.

Comment: I know this is getting off topic, but just quickly, what is there a reason to put the <?php code on different lines? does it help the code run any smoother or is it purely to make it easier to read when editing? I'm curious behind the reasoning, thanks in advance.

Comment: It's only for readability. It's more or less the same reason why you'll put the first line of a block on the line following an opening curly (`{`) rather than on the same line, or the reason why you'll put the first element in a large <div> on the following line, rather than on the same line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form action="" method"post">
```

should be

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

your form is defaulting to `GET` because it doesn't have the method represented correctly so then $_POST is empty so your foreach doesn't have anything to check.

Comment: ahh crap, I checked over the code at the top again and again and missed something silly, thanks for the reply.

Comment: @user2542256 if it makes you feel better I stared at it for about 5 minutes before I saw it.

Comment: I think I was relying dreamweaver to auto put ="" like it normally does, for some reason it decided not to, never overlook the obvious I guess, thanks again.

Comment: You should try to code without Dreamweaver in the future. It's better practice, and to be honest, sometimes Dreamweaver can hatch you some pretty awful code, if you're not careful. A good old text editor with syntax highlighting like Notepad++ is, according to me, going to be more instructive.